# Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string

Tags: php

```
$startdate = new DateTime("2013-11-15");
$enddate = new DateTime("2013-11-20");
$timestamp_start = strtotime($startdate);
$timestamp_end = strtotime($enddate);
$difference = abs($timestamp_end - $timestamp_start); 
$days = floor($difference/(60*60*24));
echo " ";
echo 'Days '.$days;
$months = floor($difference/(60*60*24*30));
echo 'Months '.$months;
$years = floor($difference/(60*60*24*365));
echo 'Years '.$years ;
echo " ";
```

before you answer, let me clariofy that my hosting provider doesnt support the version of php higher than 5.2, so dont suggest diff and interval functions.

i am getting Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, please help.

Comment: `$startdate`/`$enddate` are `DateTime`'s - not strings. You literally just declared them as `DateTime`? What about it seems weird?

Comment: doesnt it parse internally?

Comment: Nope - why would you even need the `DateTime` class any way when you don't use it?

Comment: *hosting provider doesnt support php higher than 5.2* -- Then you are with a bad hosting provider, and you should switch to a better host as soon as possible. PHP 5.2 was end-of-life at the end of 2010; it hasn't had any security updates in nearly four years. Any hosting provider that still has it on their servers after all this time is being negligent, and is probably wide open to being hacked. I suggest you find a better host.

Comment: @Spudley its wellknown hosting provider, you must have heard about host gator.

Comment: That just makes it worse. Have you asked them why your PHP version is so badly out of date? If you're paying for their service, I think you should at least be getting an up-to-date and secure server. Contact their support desk and ask.

Comment: @Spudley i contacted them, they said we cant upgrade the server, we have plenty of customers, that may affect other customers data, and i found that answer very wiered!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$startdate` and `$enddate` are DateTime objects, not strings. [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) requires a string, and you should simply pass a string instead, like so:

```
$startdate = "2013-11-15";
$enddate = "2013-11-20";
```

I'd recommend ugprading to a higher PHP version, if possible. `DateTime` class is the best way to go when you're dealing with times and dates in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I have a function that does what I think you want.

You just need to pass it to dates and it will tell yu the difference between the 2

```
function getDateDifference($start_date, $end_date) {

    $diff = abs(strtotime($end_date) - strtotime($start_date));
    $years = floor($diff / (365*60*60*24));
    $months = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24) / (30*60*60*24));
    $days = floor(($diff - $years * 365*60*60*24 - $months*30*60*60*24)/ (60*60*24));

    if($years == 1) {
        $year_str = ' year';
    }
    else {
        $year_str = ' years';
    }
    if($months == 1) {
        $month_str = ' month';
    }
    else {
        $month_str = ' months';
    }
    if($days == 1) {
        $day_str = ' day';
    }
    else {
        $day_str = ' days';
    }

    if($years == 0) {

        if($months == 0) {

            return $days.$day_str;
        }
        return $months.$month_str. ' '.$days.$day_str;
    }
    else {
        return $years.$year_str.' '.$months.$month_str. ' '.$days.$day_str;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of `new DateTime` for `strtotime()`

```
$timestamp_start = strtotime("2013-11-15");
$timestamp_end = strtotime("2013-11-20");
```