# save sql datetime to php variables

Tags: php, sql

```php
$date =$row2['DeliveryDate'];
```

`$date` now contains the date variable as a datetime, to display it I would use:

```php
echo date_format($date, 'm-d-y');
```

the problem I'm having is extracting single values from $date for example:

```php
$datetime = strtotime($row2['DeliveryDate']);
$mysqldate = date("d", $datetime);
```

returns this error:

```
Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in
C:\xampp\htdocs\tutorials\DerBlatt\hebrewDateTrial.php on line 10
```

I've tried numerous ways to extract the day/month/year into single variables but nothing works
if someone can suggest a way it might work I'll be very greatfull;
I've copy/pasted code from many sites but all of them use an example of the date as a string, unfortunately i haven't found a solution for the datetime variable.

I wanna do something like:

```php
$date =$row2['DeliveryDate'];
//whatever conversion code that comes in between.
$d = //the day from datetime
$m = //the month from datetime
$y = //the year from datetime
```

Comment: This is extremely easy to find via a Search Engine (E.G. Google). What have you tried?

Comment: strottime(), date('d', $date) and many more ways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so this is how i made it work (very funny)...

```
$m = date_format($row2['DeliveryDate'], 'm');
$d = date_format($row2['DeliveryDate'], 'd');
$y = date_format($row2['DeliveryDate'], 'y');
echo 'Month: '.$m.' Day: '.$d.' Year: '.$y;
```

Thank you guys for helping me, sometimes my best solution is just using my head...

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PHP 5.3 or better ,use the [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class .

if you want to display in this format `$format='m-d-y';`

**Retrieving data from database .**

```
$date =$row2['DeliveryDate'];
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i:s',$date);
if($date){ // if the date is correct
    $yourdate = $date->format($format);
    $year = $date->format('Y');
    $month = $date->format('m');
    $day = $date->format('d');
}
```

**Saving to database .**

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat($format,$date);    
if($date){
    $date = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $row2['DeliveryDate'] = $date;
}else{
    $row2['DeliveryDate'] = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
}
```

Comment: I've found a solution and added it as an answer, but i will try this to see if it works too. Thanks

Comment: so i tried it and i get the error: DateTime::createFromFormat() expects at least 2 parameters, 1 given in... as i mentioned in the previous comment i already have a solution and i posted it Thank you

Comment: @Abodu Tahiri DateTime::createFromFormat() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in      Thanks for the help i posted the answer already

Comment: yes i update the solution , its just another solution .. Good luck bro :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
echo date('d',strtotime($row2['DeliveryDate']));
```

i think it will work.

Comment: nope it doesn't i mentioned in the question that i tried strtotime() but it needs a string, not a variable error: Warning: strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given in C:\

Comment: That doesn't mean the solution is wrong, it means that you're sending an object but not a string. The error is there, throw it in Google and understand the problem.

Comment: @effy http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20073324/warning-strtotime-expects-parameter-1-to-be-string here there is a question about your situation

Comment: @Gorkem Yontem thats a different situation i need to convert a datetime object not a string   btw i already came up with a solution